# Default Apache virtual host configuration with static ip

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, apache-2.4, static-ip

I recently configured an (Ubuntu 14.04) server to use static IP addresses and noticed that:
`<Virtualhost *:80>`

No longer seems to work. Previously the 000-default.conf file was used and by modifying it and adding each IP to the declaration it works again.  But I'd rather be able to use a wildcard here and elsewhere if possible.

Most of the hosts I have configured are now explicitly stating which IP address(es) they correspond to, is there a way to configure apache so that the default (or ***any***) virtual host configuration that will be used for any and all hostnames which don't have a match using a wildcard?

Comment: I've always used `<VirtualHost _default:80>` for that. The documentation seems to suggest, that it still is available in 2.4 (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html#default). Have you tried that?

Comment: It's supposed to be: `<VirtualHost _default_:80>`

Comment: Earlier in that same docs page it's illustrated that the first vhost `<Virtualhost *:80>` in the config will be used if no others match.  This only stopped working for me when I configured static IPs.

Answer (score 0):

In your main httpd.conf you want your "Listen" directive to be

```
Listen 80
```

then you should have each virtual begin with:

```
<VirtualHost *>
```

that's how I have apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 12 working

Comment: As far as I know Apache 2.4 is not officially supported on Ubuntu 12.  In any event, `Listen 80` is already there by default in ports.conf and using wildcards no longer seems to work in virtual hosts.  Are you using DHCP or static IP configuration?

Comment: static ip, the wildcard seems to work on my virtual host - I could do some further testing if it's not working for you...?